# yosemite on yosemite in virtualbox

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I would like to run yosemite in virtualbox on yosemite. I've tried many step-by-step guides, without success. While there is a lot of descriptions on how to install hacked OS X on windows, I want to stay legal and use unmodified OS X, only in a virtualized manner.

Tried:

- create ISO from /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app (at least two different ways) and supply it as Bootable CD and
- create bootable USB and attached it as virtual disk

but boot always get stuck with `Missing Bluetooth Controller Transport!` message. There is a youtube video on how to eliminate this issue, but I'm not sure on how to set boot flags in virtualbox (tried: `VBoxManage setextradata osx "VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs"  "-s"`, then boot displayed bash prompt for a second, but couldn't type anything there). I've also tried to set cpuidset (was suggested in one article) via `VBoxManage modifyvm osx --cpuidset 1 000206a7 02100800 1fbae3bf bfebfbff`, but that made no difference, neither.

I need all this hassle, because I want to create a build environment setup script, therefore

1. I should be able to throw away my os state at any time and start fresh.

Also

1. I don't want to install every sort of dev tools, because I want to keep clean my machine for daily use and
2. I want to be able to have multiple dev environments with different setups (for work and for my sandbox projects)

I'm also new to mac community. I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use VMware Fusion to run OS X in a virtual machine.  It's not free like VirtualBox however it's much better then VirtualBox.  Also installing OS X in a VM under VMware Fusion is straight forward compared to VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

Download [`Install OS X Yosemite` from the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-yosemite/id915041082?mt=12).
Use [`iesd`](https://rubygems.org/gems/iesd/) to create a bootable `dmg`:

```
iesd -i "/Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app"/ -o yosemite.dmg -t BaseSystem
```

Install [VirtualBox for Mac Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Create a new VirtualBox guest. Choose `Type: [Mac OS X]` and `Version: [Mac OS X (64-bit)]`. Don't choose a specific OS version.

After you create the guest, choose it and click `Settings`->`System`->`Motherboard`->`Chipset` and choose `PIIX3`. If you leave the default `ICH9` set, the system will never boot. You'll just see a black screen in your guest window.

Choose the `yosemite.dmg` you created earlier for your guest's optical disk.

Start your guest.

You'll see a wall of text and eventually the OS X Installer screen.

Use disk utility to partition your disk into a single partition. Disk Utility will have proper defaults.

Exit disk utility and run the installer.

You'll find some steps like these below [in other places](http://sqar.blogspot.de/2014/10/installing-yosemite-in-virtualbox.html), but they didn't work for me. `iesd` worked.

```
 #!/bin/bash  

 # Mount the installer image  
 hdiutil attach /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app  

 # Convert the boot image to a sparse bundle  
 hdiutil convert /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -format UDSP -o /tmp/Yosemite  

 # Increase the sparse bundle capacity to accommodate the packages  
 hdiutil resize -size 8g /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage  

 # Mount the sparse bundle for package addition  
 hdiutil attach /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build  

 # Remove Package link and replace with actual files  
 rm /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/Packages  
 cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/  

 # Copy Base System  
 cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/install_build/  
 cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/install_build/  

 # Unmount the installer image  
 hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app  

 # Unmount the sparse bundle  
 hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_build  

 # Resize the partition in the sparse bundle to remove any free space  
 hdiutil resize -size `hdiutil resize -limits /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`b /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage  

 # Convert the sparse bundle to ISO/CD master  
 hdiutil convert /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage -format UDTO -o /tmp/Yosemite  

 # Remove the sparse bundle  
 rm /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage  

 # Rename the ISO and move it to the desktop  
 mv /tmp/Yosemite.cdr ~/Desktop/Yosemite.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you've stopped the virtual machine before you ran the command `VBoxManage modifyvm osx --cpuidset 1 000206a7 02100800 1fbae3bf bfebfbff`?

I [wrote an detailed guide for virtualized Yosemite](https://gist.github.com/frdmn/de12c894a385bc8e6bff) some time ago and ran into the same issue which I could fix with said command.

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the step-by-step guide I followed, but I couldn't make it work :( When I get some time, I'll try one more time. (BTW, it was a nice post).

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if it still doesn't work. I'll do my best to help you out. Make sure to reply in here, since I don't really get notified on the Gist comments if I don't check manually.